# One who pays for learning Torah gets all the respect

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

When discussing precedence of honoring one's Rabbi vs one's father, Poskim (*see "Psakim and Teshuvos" by Aharon Katz on יו"ד ר"מ for the list*) note that if the father (or someone else) pays the Rabbi, the former gets all the Rabbi's honor.

We know, however, that **a Rabbi is obligated to teach for free anyway**, **the father cannot pay him the fee of teaching**, but only a compensation for possible loss of a "real work income" (ha-ha-ha). Maybe the Rabbi becomes a Shaliah?

I was wondering **what's the connection**?

Also, how does it apply to the current day Yeshivos, where the Rabbis got paid thru fathers and outside donors - who get the respect?

*(Am I limited on how many questions I can ask on one topic in one week?)*

Comment: There is no formal limit on number of questions per topic per week (that I know of). There is a limit to how many questions you can ask (and how much time between questions) but this is to limit spam or abuse - I don't think you are likely to run into this as long as you act normally :->

Comment: “We know, however...” Do we? Where do we know this from? (I know I’ve asked a lot of these types of questions on your posts recently. My only point with them is to encourage you to post your sources in the OP itself. Not everyone is familiar with this topic as you are.)